# Ошибка при сборке проекта Android Studio

Tags: android

Ребят, подскажите, что это и с чем это может быть связано. А самое главное, как попасть на эту самую строку 627? 
В общем, проект был полностью рабочий, но полетела винда. Проект я сохранил, а после переустановки Студии не могу его собрать. Все, что нужно было я подгрузил, все синхронизировал, на что ругалась Студия. И мне кажется, что я подобное уже как-то получал, но тогда сделал. Кажется, в build.gradle что-то менял
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
build.gradle
```

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.bluetooth_communication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Ну... Покажите `Build.gradle`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил

Comment: Попробуйте вот так получить больше информации об ошибке: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674403/3212712

Comment: подозреваю, что тесты берут откуда-то "фейковый" json (из файла например), который некорректен

Comment: @CottonPericranium, таки да. Попробуйте все тестовые зависимости убрать.

Comment: @ извините, я не совсем понимаю, что это. можете пояснить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я не знаю, что я сделал, но я починил. я бы написал это в ответ, но у меня нет понимания, что я все-таки сделал) баловался со строчкой  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'. цифры другие были, не помню какие, поменял на 2.2.2., вылезло еще больше ошибок, поставил 2.3.3. и все заработало

Comment: @CottonPericranium, вы можете в истории изменений файла посмотреть что было. Возможно у вас там 3 версия стояла